# require_once not working in one file but working in the other

Tags: php, require-once

I've got this weird problem in getting an error

> Undefined variable: sqlConn

And it can't be a connection to DB problem because it would yell another error, whats even stranger is that te require_once thats identical in a file thats in the same directory works just fine. I don't even know what to think.
Here's one (WORKING) file:

```
<?php require_once("connect.php");?>
<html>
<head>...
..........
...<?php
foreach($sqlConn->query('SELECT * FROM permatable') as $row) {
echo "<tr><td>".$row["Art"]."</td><td>".$row["Ime"]."</td><td>".$row["Uvoz"]."</td><td>".$row["Opis"]."</td><td>".$row["Cijena"]."</td></tr>";
}
?>
```

And the other (Getting an error):

```
<?php require_once("connect.php");?>
<?php

if(isset($_POST["AddFromDB"], $_POST["ArtNo"])){
    addExisting($_POST["ArtNo"]);
} 
else if(isset($_POST["AddNew"], $_POST["Art"], $_POST["ImeProizvoda"], $_POST["Dobava"], $_POST["Cijena"])){
    newItem($_POST["Art"], $_POST["ImeProizvoda"], $_POST["Dobava"], $_POST["Cijena"]);
}
if(isset($_POST["clearList"])){
    clearPermaTB();
} 
else if (!isset ($_POST)){
    echo "error";
}

//Dodaj postojeci proizvod
function addExisting ($Art) {
    echo "5";
    //Trazi u bazi
    $result_set = $sqlConn->query("SELECT Art, Ime, Uvoz, Opis, Cijena FROM proizvod WHERE Art = '{$Art}'");
```

So again, both are in the same directory, both use similar code, but for some reason one gets the error and the other doesen't.

Here's a connect file:

```
    //Database Connection
$sqlConn =  new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $name);
if ($sqlConn->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
?>
```

Am I making an sql syntax mistake?

Comment: `$sqlConn` is not declared in scope in the second php. check [Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `sqlConn` is out of scope.
You're trying to call it from your function.

You could pass it as an argument to your function or use `global` even if it's not a good design

Solution 1:

```
addExisting(xxx, $sqlConn);
// ...
function addExisting($Art, $sqlConn)
{
   // use $sqlConn here
}
```

Solution 2:

```
addExisting(xxx);
// ...
function addExisting($Art)
{
   global $sqlConn;
   // use $sqlConn here
}
```